# Plain Selenium and Thucydides reports

Tags: java, maven, selenium, report, thucydides

I have plain seleneum ui tests and I want to have nice thucydides reports after how can I do this.
In maven pom.xml I have profile like this:

```
 <profile>
            <id>MobileTests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                            <argLine>-Dwebdriver.remote.url=http://192.168.1.5/wd/hub</argLine>
                            <groups>ru.testgroups.mobile.AllMobile</groups>

                        </configuration>

                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportPlugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>net.thucydides.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-thucydides-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <version>${thucydides.version}</version>
                                </plugin>
                            </reportPlugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
```

It suppose to generate reports, but it does not. How can I get thucydides reports from plain selenium tests

Answer (score 0):

You should add the serenity (or thucydides, if you're using an older version) as a **reporting** plugin:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: I have to add serenety to where Sir. In my <dependencies> and that it? Or have to move thucydides as well??